# Mapping a dictionary to a tableview in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to populate a tableview with realtime stock ticker data that is provided by the server in the form of an unordered `Dictionary<symbol, price>`, i.e -

```
{
  "APPL":94.02,
  "GOOG":683.00,
  "FB":104.07
}
```

What I want to do is fetch new stock data every second or so, diff the retrieved data against my model and only update the specific table cells that have changed. However, I'm not sure what the best approach would be to update specific cells since the data comes in unordered and tableviews are index based.

It seems like my options would be either to:

1. create an intermediate `[symbol:index]` dictionary to store index locations, so I can later reference and update them
2. convert the fetched data to an array of values, sort it, perform a diff against my model to find the indexes that have changed, then use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`

Option 1 seems viable, but inflexible. There'd be no easy way to sort my table rows later on.
Options 2 seems flimsy. It's based on the assumption that the incoming data will never change. It also seems like it would be resource intensive to do this with every update.

Is there a better way of handing the unordered datatype -> tableview mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry that the dictionary of prices is not sorted. Just have an array of the ticker symbols in the order you want them (e.g. an array called `tickerSymbols` with `["APPL", "FB", "GOOG"]`). Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can do something like:

```
let tickerSymbol = tickerSymbols[indexPath.row]
if let price = stockPrices[tickerSymbol] {
    // update cell with `price`
}
```

The retrieving of the contents from the dictionary is sufficiently efficient that in most cases the above should work reasonably well.